Why does my question get locked by on Askubuntu? No apparant reason other than a bully moderator
I am experiencing this unhelpful behaviour accross this community of forums related to stack exchange and stack overflow

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is not a forum. This is a question answer site. You may want to read the site help to understand what questions you may ask here. I don't see any other questions under your name on this site.

I don't see this on Ask Ubuntu? You have a question that you deleted and this question that has been migrated from the main Ask Ubuntu site.

By the way, if you don't post questions that can actually be answered (meaning that you just post junk or something that has no details, etc.) then NO site can help you, and if you get requests for more info you have to provide it or nobody can help you.

You have no posts on Ask Ubuntu that were deleted by a moderator.  Only by yourself.  And this one which was mis-posted on Ask Ubuntu.
Therefore, your premise for your post is nonexistent.
If you are talking about on Stack Overflow and StackExchange, that has nothing to do with Ask Ubuntu, and this is not the place for you to be ranting.

I deleted it myself seeing the downvotes. Plus Askubuntu is a part of Stack exchange network and has the same kind of rude behaviour I've bumped into in my brief experience on the networks. So it isn't unrelated. But yes it isn't exactly as sour here.

BTW you being the moderator, who moderates a moderator? Just asking.

@NAYANC. the Community Managers - paid staff at StackExchange - are in charge of moderating moderators.  That's what the "Contact" button at the bottom of pages is for.  HOWEVER, if you delete your post because it gets downvotes, that triggers certain things in the system that MAY block you from posting questions or answers.  Downvotes plus deletes tends to trigger that more than just downvotes + closed question.  You should AVOID deleting your posts JUST because of downvotes.

USUALLY Downvotes are because your question is incomplete or not capable of being answered or poor quality.  That's not uncommon, that does NOT however equate to problems with the site/team.  You actually have to post questions with enough details to help AND be responsive.  DO NOT take Downvotes as personal attacks.

Thanks. This is a helpful answer. I'll be mindful of this in my future posts.
